# WCF Load Test with Visual Studio or any other free tools

Tags: wcf

We have a WCF web service and I would like to perform a load test. Could anyone please confirm if this is possible via Visual Studio 2010 or any other free tools?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have done a decent amount of this over the last five years using mstest and jetbrains dottrace.

What you need to do is write an integration test (a unit test that makes a call to your service) and then reference that in a load test. I then get dottrace to profile IIS and then rune the load test.

Answer (score 0):

A free tool is available from [CodePlex to load test WCF.](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/) To quote the project description:

`This tool takes a WCF trace file and a WCF client proxy, or a WCF interface contract, and generates a C# unit test that replays the same sequence of calls found in the trace file. The unit test can then be used to load-test the target`

Answer (score 0):

You can with VS as long as you own the ultimate edition.